# Is my proof of a seemingly trivial question involving infinite sums correct?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Given that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n^2<\infty$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n^2<\infty$, where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are sequences of real numbers,

I'm trying to show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_nb_n)^2<\infty$.

So I write

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_nb_n)^2=\sum_{m,n=0,n=m}^{\infty}(a_nb_m)^2<\sum_{m,n=0}^{\infty}(a_nb_m)^2<\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_n)^2.\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(b_m)^2<\infty$.

Is there some mistake in any of the above steps? Basically, I'm trying to show that the product of two square summable sequences is square summable.

Comment: The first sum is $\le$ the product of sums, yes. But you could also just say $(a_nb_n)^2 \le a_n^2$ for large $n.$

Comment: Absolutely correct, just like the answer of @zhw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean something like

$$
\sum_n a_n^2 b_n^2 = \sum_n a_n^2 \sum_m \delta_{n,m} b_m^2
                   < \sum_n a_n^2 \sum_m b_m^2
                   < \infty
$$

where $\delta_{n,m} = 1 \mbox{ if } n = m, 0$ otherwise, is the indicator function, then that seems all right.

Answer (score 0):

$l^2$ is a vector space, so that if $a_n,b_n$ are in $l^2$, so is $a_n+b_n$, meaning that $$\Sigma (a_n+b_n)^2 = \Sigma a_n^2 +2\Sigma a_n b_n + \Sigma b_n^2 < \infty $$. This means $\Sigma a_nb_n < \infty \in l^1$, so it is in $l^2$.

Comment: I was just verifying that $l^2$ is closed under products. Of course, once you assume $l^2$ is a vector space, the claim is trivial.

Comment: I think it is not so hard to show that $l^p$ is closed under sums . Though maybe not trivial.

Comment: Wouldn't Cauchy-Schwarz prove it right away?

Comment: @gary: It's always the trivial points that have a million different one-line proofs. :-)